# Firebase not being written to and no errors not being thrown

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating a web app to which I am using Firebase as my main database.

For a few protoypes I have been able to update and write data to the database as needed but as of a few weeks ago, before and after I updated the SDK and all, it has stopped adding to the database.
Here is my code for calling and writing to the database

```
DatabaseReference data;

public void Send(String jobName, Genome currentGenome, Gene currentGene) throws FileNotFoundException {
    FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream(ResultstoFirebaseCopy.class.getClassLoader()
            .getResource("<Admin Authentication>.json").getPath()
            .replaceAll("%20", " "));

    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setCredential(FirebaseCredentials.fromCertificate(serviceAccount))
            .setDatabaseUrl("https://<projectname>.firebaseio.com/").build();

    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

    data=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    // loop through with results from genome class
    System.out.println(currentGenome.getGenome());

    DatabaseReference cellref = Genespot.child(jobName).child(currentGenome.getKingdom())
            .child(currentGenome.getSubType()).child(currentGenome.getTaxID())
            .child(currentGenome.getGenome().replace('.', 'v')).child(currentGene.getName());

    Hit[] hits = currentGene.getHits();

    cellref.child("Hit Count").setValue(hits.length, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError arg0, DatabaseReference arg1) {
            throw arg0.toException();
        }
    });

    int i = 0;

    while (i < hits.length) {
        cellref.child("Hit" + (i + 1)).child("Accession Number").setValue(
                hits[i].getAccesionNumber().replace('.', 'v'), new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(DatabaseError arg0, DatabaseReference arg1) {
                        throw arg0.toException();
                    }
                });
        cellref.child("Hit" + (i + 1)).child("Hit From").setValue(hits[i].getHitFrom(),
                new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(DatabaseError arg0, DatabaseReference arg1) {
                        throw arg0.toException();
                    }
                });
        cellref.child("Hit" + (i + 1)).child("Hit To").setValue(hits[i].getHitTo(),
                new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(DatabaseError arg0, DatabaseReference arg1) {
                        throw arg0.toException();
                    }
                });

        i++;
    }
}
```

Read and write access are true and nothing is getting thrown back at me.